# Quadratic equation positive roots.

Tags: quadratics

I have a question which says that if the roots of the equation $$x^4-12x^3+cx^2+dx+81=0$$ are positive, then what is the value of $c$ and $d$.

I am currently doing High school algebra and haven't had any calculus training and I believe that this question involves the knowledge of differential calculus. Can anybody please help me with this question by using algebraic methods only. Any kind of hint would suffice, I just want to know where can I start up.

Comment: Do you have more information? It seems unlikely to be able to deduce $c$ and $d$ just from knowing the signs of the roots.

Comment: That's the same problem that I faced, but the question just ends here. I could only deduce some trivial conclusion like $c>0$, $d>0$ nothing more than that.

Comment: It seems like $(x-3)^4$ could be the poly you are looking for

Comment: If you knew the value of two roots you could find $c$ and $d$ by solving a linear system.

Comment: But there is nothing more given then how do we figure out such thing?

Comment: @FrancescoBaccetti How did you get it?

Comment: Does it say that all 4 roots *exist*?

Comment: @fleablood        They are positive which means that they must exist.

Comment: Yes, but how many.  Either there are 0 roots, 2 roots, or 4 (counting double roots).  And are all the coefficients integers?

Comment: @fleablood all the coefficients are integers and  I suppose all must be positive (all four)

Comment: Then see my solution.  BUT I feel that assuming the coefficients are integers and that there are four (rather than two) solutions are assumptions we shouldn't be allowed to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there are 4 roots (not 2 or 0) and assuming all coeficients are integers.

If the roots are $a, b ,c, d$ then $x^4 - 12x^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + 81 = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$

$=x^4 - (a+b+c+d)x^3 +(ab + ac + ad + bc + bd+cd)x^2 - (abc + abd+acd+bcd)x + abcd$

So

1)$a+b+c+d = 12$

2)$ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd = C$

3)$abc + abd +acd+bcd = -D$

4)$abcd = 81$

Combining 1) and 4) there are only so many possiblities if we asssume $a,b,c,d$ are all positive integers.  $a,b,c,d$ must be $1$ or multiples of $3$ as $abcd = 3^4$.  But $a+b+c + d = 12$ so only one is as large as $9$ (because $9+9+1+1 > 12$).  But if one is $9$ then two must be $3$ and $9 + 3+3+1 > 12$.  So at most they are $3$.  But there must be four $3$s so $3+3+3+3 = 12$ and ($a=b=c=d=3$).

[If that was a little too talky... consider if $abcd = 81$ then $\{a,b,c,d\} = $ $\{81,1,1,1\}$ or $\{27,3,1,1\}$ or $\{9,9,1,1\}$ or $\{9,3,3,1\}$ or $\{3,3,3,3\}$. $\{3,3,3,3\}$ is the only option where $a+b+c+d = 12$.]

So

$ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd = 9+9+9+9+9+9 = 54 =C$ and $abc + abd +acd+bcd = =27+27+27+27=108=-D; d=-108$

[and $x^4 - 12x^3 + 54x^2 -104x + 81= x^4 - 4*3*x^3 + 6*3^2*x^2 - 4*3^3*x + 3^4= (x-3)^4$]

Comment: Just awesome!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You dont need to use hit and trial. Simply use AM GM inequality to get p=q=r=s=3.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,q,r,s$ be the roots of $f(x)$.

Sum of roots=$p+q+r+s=12$ and product of roots=$pqrs=81$. It takes some hit and trial to reach that $p=q=r=s=3$. Now, $(x-3)^4=f(x)$.

Comment: Accidentally I posted it as an answer..Now struggling to delete it. Tell me how.